# Django: get rid of the label in model fields

Tags: django, django-models, label

So I have this models:

```
class ProfileImage(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
    verbose_name=_('User'),
    to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    related_name='profile',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image')
```

How can I get rid of the label "avatar:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have a form for your model, you need to make again the avatar and add

```
avatar = forms.Imagefield(label='')
```